# Squeeze theorem

Tags: calculus

Is there any trick when it comes two find two sequences with the same limit to prove that a third sequence that is between them has also a limit? There are a whole bunch of sequences with the same limit.

As an example, $\lim_{n \to \infty}\{\frac{n}{2n^2+1}+\frac{n}{2n^2+2}+\dots+\frac{n}{2n^2+n}\}$.

Comment: Allsony, Can you give any example question?

Comment: $lim\{\frac{1}{2n^2+1}+\frac{n}{2n^2+2}+\dots+\frac{n}{2n^2+n}\}$

Comment: You should edit your question once. Add this into your question. Also specify the limit of $n$, like $\lim_{n\to 0}$

Comment: When it comes to sequences it's always supposed that n goes to infinity :d.

Comment: @Allonsy, not always, although maybe **so far** for you.

Comment: by the way, I like this problem.  I will include it as a bonus on the next calculus test.

Comment: haha, why do you like it?

Answer (score 1):

You can see the correct estimate

$a_n\leq n^2/(2n^2+1)$ since you have a sum of $n$ things less than or equal to $n/(2n^2+1)$.

$n^2/(2n^2+n) \leq a_n$ since you have a sum of $n$ things greater than or equal to $n/(2n^2+n)$.

In general, you try to reduce the complexity of the expression for the $n$th term of a sequence and see how the original sequence compares.  It often helps to know that part of the expression is bounded.  For instance, we know that $-1\leq$sin$2n\leq 1$, so we have

$-1/(1+\sqrt n)\leq ($sin$2n)/(1+\sqrt n)\leq 1/(1+\sqrt n)$,

whence by the squeeze theorem

lim$_{n\to\infty} ($sin$2n)/(1+\sqrt n)=0$.

Comment: The limit of the sequence is $\frac12$, since $\frac{n^2}{2n^2+n} \le\{\frac{1}{2n^2+1}+\frac{n}{2n^2+2}+\dots+\frac{n}{2n^2+n}\} \le \frac{n^2}{2n^2+1}$. The sequences above have limit $\frac12$, and by the squeeze  theorem, $\{\frac{1}{2n^2+1}+\frac{n}{2n^2+2}+\dots+\frac{n}{2n^2+n}\}$ has limit $\frac12$.

Comment: Note that I didn't find out that answer, that's what it comes in the book. I don't even know if its true because I can't even see that the original sequence is between that two sequences.

Comment: There is no way that is true!

Comment: I think you wrote the problem incorrectly: look at the numerators.  Did you mean for the powers of $n$ to be going from $0$ to $n$ maybe?

Comment: The first numerator is 1, the second is n, the third is n, the nth is n. The first is 1, the others are n.

Comment: and the denominator is $2n^2+1, 2n^2+2,...,2n^2+n$

Comment: What I mean is what is it ><. Also it's easy to see that $\frac{n^2}{2n^2+n} \le $ the original sequence testing with n's.

Comment: Hm yes, you're right

Comment: ok, I misunderstood your sequence, let me try again

Comment: No, no, you didn't. The thing is when n=2, the first element is evaluated with n=2 or with n=1?. I think you're right, evaluating with n=2.

Comment: Sorry, there's a typo in the book. The first numerator is n ):

Comment: yeah something is wrong with that estimate...

Comment: Still, the limit is 1/2.

Comment: yes it will be 1/2.  I have verified the estimate.

Comment: I fixed what I assume was a typo. Please check to make sure I did not alter what you had intended.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, I would just take the minimum term and the maximum term and replace all terms by that term. That is, since there are $n$ terms in the sum,
$$
n\frac{n}{2n^2+n}\le\frac{n}{2n^2+1}+\frac{n}{2n^2+2}+\dots+\frac{n}{2n^2+n}\le n\frac{n}{2n^2+1}
$$
Then we can simplify the left and right sides to be things whose limit can more easily be seen:
$$
\frac1{2+1/n}\le\frac{n}{2n^2+1}+\frac{n}{2n^2+2}+\dots+\frac{n}{2n^2+n}\le \frac1{2+1/n^2}
$$